# Not receving push notification android sinch app sample

Tags: android, push-notification, sinch

I am developing an android app with sinch integration, I try the sample code after many time trying in my code. I am not receiving push notification for call at all. In fact I debug my GcmBroadcastReceiver and I got others incoming intents for other apps services. I am trying in an android 4.4.2 device.

When i trying call the device in the web app sample returns TIMEOUT ERROR. In the other way from device to web app works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey based on the information you have provided I don't know what to point to, but back when I was working with notifications on Android I made a simple push notifications demo app (it uses Azure notification hubs and Parse server): https://github.com/pacificpelican/kirkland

Comment: My Bad is a sinch integration